# Django REST Framework the field was declared on serializer but not included

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I include `board_field` in the `UserSerializer` definition, I get:

> AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'board_field'

if I exclude it, I get:

> the field was declared on serializer but not included

I am using default Django `User` model, but what I want to serialize is a reverse foreign key relation from my `Board` model.

First of all, I have this project structure.

```
foo_project
    - foo_project
         - __init__.py
         - asgi.py
         - settings.py
         - urls.py
         - wsgi.py
    - apps
       - board
           - __init__.py
           - admin.py
           - apps.py
           - models.py
           - serializers.py
           - tests.py
           - urls.py
           - views.py
       - accounts
           - __init__.py
           - admin.py
           - apps.py
           - models.py
           - serializers.py
           - tests.py
           - urls.py
           - views.py
```

Board,

```py
# models.py
class Board(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    title = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    body = models.TextField(blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='time_line_photo')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Board
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BoardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Board
        fields = ('id', 'author', 'title', 'body', 'image', 'created','updated')

# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render

from rest_framework import generics

from .models import Board
from .serializers import BoardSerializer

class BoardList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Board.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BoardSerializer

class BoardDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Board.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BoardSerialize
```

Accounts,

```py
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from ..board.models import Board

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    board_field = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Board.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'board_field') 
# If I include board_field, I get AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'board_field'
# I understand that I am using default django User model, but it is foreign key in Board model.

# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics

from .serializers import UserSerializer

class UserList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerialize
```

As I state in the comment, I think that is my issue. How can UserSerializer hook up with Board?
I am using,
python=3.7.4 
django=3.0.4
djangorestframework=3.11.0
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the documentation of [reverse relations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#reverse-relations). The `User` model doesn't have a field called `board_field` and that's why you see that error.

I see that you have already used `related_name='user'` in the `Board` model. But do note that the related name is used for reverse relations e.g. in this case it should be from author's perspective. You can name it `boards` instead of `user`.

```
class Board(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='boards')
```

Because the related name is set, you can use that in the `UserSerializer`:

```
boards = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    many=True, queryset=Board.objects.all()
)

# also don't forget to include that in list of fields
```